# Update Marketo lead's membership->progressionStatus using REST API

Tags: rest, marketo, lead

I'm trying to adapt https://github.com/Marketo/REST-Sample-Code/blob/master/php/LeadDatabase/Leads/SyncLeads.php for my own needs. I want to be able to update a lead's status from "Registered" to "Attended" using the REST API. (The Marketo Events app does this when someone is checked into an event.)

However, when I try sending something like:

```
{"input":[{"email":"asdfasdf@qwerqwer.org",
           "membership":{"progressionStatus":"Attended"}}]}
```

I get back:

```
{"requestId":"168be#15868ee5bff",
 "result":[{"status":"skipped","reasons":[
     {"code":"1006","message":"Field 'membership' not found"}]}],
 "success":true}
```

I understand the message just fine -- 'membership' isn't a field, therefore it can't be updated this way. But is there another way to update the `progressionStatus` using the API?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be looking at that lead's membership of the program - see this method for more information: http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/endpoint-reference/lead-database-endpoint-reference/#!/Leads/changeLeadProgramStatusUsingPOST

Comment: The documentation appears to be incomplete -- see `changeLeadProgramStatusRequest`? There's no guidance for what `LeadLookupInputData` should look like.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this format:

```
{
    'status': 'Member',
    'input': [
        {'id': 23},
        {'id': 445}
    ]
}
```

You have to use the Marketo Lead ID (not email) and you can only specify 1 status value per API call. Max batch size is 300 Lead IDs.